# Show CircularProgressIndicator while loading URL in Web View

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to show `CircularProgressIndicator` when ever the `webview` loads an URL. Below is code but it only shows loading element while initializing the `webview`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new MaterialApp(
      theme
        : new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0), fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          url: url,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(null),
              )
            ],
          ),
          withJavascript: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
          appCacheEnabled: true,
          hidden: true,
        )
      },
    );
  }
```

I want it to show loading element when user clicks on any link within `webview`.

Answer (score 6):

its should work for first time, I know that is not exactly what's your looking for but it may help.

```
WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://www.google.com/",
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: const Text('Widget webview'),
      ),
      withZoom: true,
      withLocalStorage: true,
      hidden: true,
      initialChild: Container(
        child: const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: there is a another package named : [flutter_native_web](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_native_web), it seems like has a feature that you're looking for.

Comment: Adding hidden: true is important!

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't seem to be supported currently.

There is a pull request that seems to provide such a feature

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/pull/255

Several related issues/feature requests

- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/177
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/284
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/232
- https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin/issues/159

Comment: Is there any method to achieve it?

Comment: Now it's merged so one can do `flutterWebviewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen((progress) {
    ...
  });`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented using **IndexedStack**

```js
class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewWidgetState createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
}

class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
  var stackToShow = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: stackToShow,
      children: [
        WebView(
          initialUrl: "https://www.google.com/",
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            // when page loaded
            setState(() {
              stackToShow = 0;
            });
          },
        ),
        Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

**This will work with WebviewScaffold**

Just paste it in your Class.

```
 @override 
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _onPageProgress =
        flutterWebViewPlugin.onProgressChanged.listen(progessChange);
  }

progessChange(double event) {
    print("Page loading " + event.toString());
    if (event == 1.0) {
      flutterWebViewPlugin.show();
    } else {
      flutterWebViewPlugin.hide();
    }
  }

final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();
late StreamSubscription<double> _onPageProgress;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebviewScaffold(
        initialChild: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            color: Colors.blue,
          )),
        ),
        hidden: true,
        clearCache: true,
        withJavascript: true,
        url: "https://www.google.com/",        
    );
  }
```